# "echo $VAR | base64 -di > file" fail to execute on MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, bash, terminal

On Linux I can do:

```bash
echo ${ANDROID_KEYSTORE} | base64 -di > android/keystores/staging.keystore
```

But on MacOS, the same commands gives:

```bash
base64: option requires an argument -- i
Usage:  base64 [-hvDd] [-b num] [-i in_file] [-o out_file]
  -h, --help     display this message
  -Dd, --decode   decodes input
  -b, --break    break encoded string into num character lines
  -i, --input    input file (default: "-" for stdin)
  -o, --output   output file (default: "-" for stdout)
```

I have tried to replace `-di` with `--decode --input`, it didn't help.

1. How do I fix the iOS command?
2. Is there a command that works both on Linux (Debian/Ubuntu) and MacOS?

Comment: I never used `-i` with `base64`. Pretty sure it isn’t required!

Comment: `-i` is `input` not `ignore garbage`. macOS is not unix, you always need to check `man`

Comment: Make sens, so far to get my script working on both platform, I did prepend a line to my script: `[[ $(uname) == "Linux" ]] && alias gbase64=base64`. Do you have a better idea or only comments ?)

Comment: @Tetsujin: *"macOS is not unix"*. Did you meant "Linux" rather then "unix" ?

Comment: @PierU - I mean it's not generic. It has its own foibles.

Answer (score 0):

If you want portability, you'll have to implement the linux-flavour's `-i` yourself

```sh
# don't forget to quote the variable!
echo "${ANDROID_KEYSTORE}" \
| sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]//g' \
| base64 -d
```

The sed command drops [invalid characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table_from_RFC_4648), [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/723150/how-to-decode-infile-base64-for-both-linux-and-macos/723154#723154)